# Is putting files in a HDD with NTFS which is part of a Windows system dangerous?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have two Windows systems. One of them is damaged and I'd like to copy the files from one system's HDD to another while I'm booted into an Ubunut Live CD. After that I'd like to reinstall Windows than put the saved files back on the HDD and delete the files from the other HDD and put the HDD back in the other machine with Windows.

Can mounting the HDD with Windows system under Ubuntu and putting files on it damage the Windows system or the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is minimal risk to the *other* windows systems by mounting the drive(s) in Ubuntu and then copying data to/from them.  There is somewhat *more* risk to the specific partitions you're mounting, and if they're not the other Windows' system partitions, then it won't impact the specific Windows systems themselves. Consider that this is something done regularly for large-size hard drives that aren't Mac OS formatted (HFS, HFS+, etc.) but were NTFS formatted from the factory.

Note however that you need to make sure that you properly unmount the drives before connecting them to Windows (or disconnecting them from Ubuntu) to avoid issues with improper filesystem errors on NTFS, etc.  However, if you eject drives properly (or just 'shut down' normally), then it will properly unmount and as such not introduce issues.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with mounting the drive. You will want to be careful about which files you restore. your documents should be fine but you probably don't what to save the system files as something there is probably responsible for breaking windows in the first place.

Since you are backing up the files because what you do with that drive until you are sure you have all of the files you want. recovering the files after they are deleted or the disk is formatted will be much much harder. accidentally doing something like this is the biggest danger of mounting a drive assuming you have a fresh install of Ubuntu on that CD are you are careful about reading the steps of what you are doing you will be safe. if it is not a fresh version you should check what the default settings are when a new drive is mounted.

The file systems are optimized for different uses and some programs may have problems with certain file systems but simply copying files over and then back again should be fine. If you want to be extra careful you can zip the files in a zip folder (a quick google will tell you how to do that) that way you will preserve the structure in the folders until you can unzip them when you bring them back.

Comment: The files are safe. So it won't damage Windows if I add and remove text documents from the HDD with NTFS while running Ubuntu than putting it back in Windows?

Comment: @Slagathor that should be fine. If you would like a walk through tutorial on how to do what you are trying to do take a look at the [how to geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) guide on how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I've found this guide. I was just concerned about wrecking the other Windows system but it seems to be safe. Thanks for the help!